# Appending data to dropzone

Tags: dropzone.js

In my web application I have a "import users" button.  If this is clicked an AJAX popup opens which contains

a) a dropdown with a list of company names (this dropdown has id CompanyID)
b) a div called fileUpload div which is initially empty

When the CompanyID menu is used I want it to behave as follows:

a) If CompanyID=0 then disable the dropzone area
b) If CompanyID!=0 then append the companyID to the formData

The problem I have is that if someone chooses CompanyID=1 then my dropzone appears and the data is appended.  Great!  However if they then select another Company then it tries to create a new Dropzone and complains that it is already attached.

My code that gets called when someone changes the CompanyID dropdown choice so far is as follows:

```
function checkCompanySelected(CompanyID)
{
if (CompanyID==0)
    {
        // make sure dropzone div is disabled if it exists
    }
else
    {
        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#fileUploadDiv", { url: "importupload.asp"});

        myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
        formData.append("CompanyID", CompanyID);
        myDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function(file) { alert('All done'); closeImportUsersForm(); });
        });

    }
}
```

I have really been banging my head on a brick wall with this one - lots of stuff out there about setting autodiscover to false but so far no luck.

Answer (score 0):

As is so often the case about 30 minutes after posting on StackOverflow the answer suddenly hits me.  To save anyone else this battle here is my code:

```
function checkCompanySelected(CompanyID)
{
    document.getElementById('fileUploadDiv').innerHTML="";

if (CompanyID==0)
    {
        // make sure dropzone div is disabled if it exists
    }
else
    {

        if (fileUploadDiv.dropzone)
        {
            fileUploadDiv.dropzone.destroy();
            var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#fileUploadDiv", { url: "importupload.asp"});
        }
        else
        {
            var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#fileUploadDiv", { url: "importupload.asp"});
        }

        myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
        formData.append("CompanyID", CompanyID);
        myDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function(file) { alert('All done'); closeImportUsersForm(); });
        });

    }
}
```

My breakthrough came after looking at the error handling if dropzone is already attached and I realised the easiest way to determine if you have a dropzone is simply to say...

```
if (fileUploadDiv.dropzone)
```

...swap fileUploadDiv for the name of your div that contains the dropzone.

Important note - you can't just say if fileUploadDiv.dropzone then do nothing as you will then get an error for the line saying it's undefined.

```
myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
```

This is strange as on the one hand it errors because it's already attached but you can also get an error for it being undefined.

So in summary we have an easy way to detect if the dropzone is active then we can destroy it and re-create it.

The autodiscover = false route was a red herring.